# Using LINQ to XML to match deeper descendant elements?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, descendant

Suppose I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <project>
    <ixGroup>105</ixGroup>
    <sGroup>Place Group</sGroup>
  </project>
  <project>
    ...
```

And I use the following code to extract the distinct `<ixGroup>` and `<sGroup>` text values from it:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\temp\xmlParse2.xml");

var projects = (from project in doc.Descendants("project")
                select new {
                    id = project.Element("ixGroup").Value,
                    name = project.Element("sGroup").Value
                }).Distinct();

foreach(var project in projects)
{
    project.id.Dump("id");
    project.name.Dump("name");
}
```

If the same xml file had an extra element like the `<projects>` one added below:

```
<response>
  <projects>
    <project>
      <ixGroup>105</ixGroup>
      <sGroup>Place Group</sGroup>
    </project>
    <project>
      ...
```

How would I modify the LINQ code above to still access the `<project>` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have to. I've just tested it, and your current LINQ statement will still return all the `<project>` elements regardless of whether they're nested within a `<projects>` element.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to modify your code at all. The `Descendants` method will search as far down the tree as it needs to in order to find matching elements, which can be both a curse and a blessing. In your case, the code as written will continue to work even if you add an intermediate `<projects>` node.

(The method that only searches for direct child methods is `Children()`.

Answer (score 0):

Elements only searches child nodes, but Descendants goes all the way down the tree.  In other words, you won't have to do anything.