# Return children using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, traversal

Using the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
      <ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>9cddb639-25ee-4415-be07-3109e5ae9883</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 0</Description>
            </Stock>
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>f89f02f9-b359-48c8-8d2f-3a950837f4fb</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 1</Description>
            </Stock>
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>3338ec80-f59e-4979-a04c-f7d52e386bb7</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 2</Description>
            </Stock>
      </ArrayOfStock>
</Message>
```

Could someone please show me how I would return just the ArrayOfStock XML?

I have used

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(this.Message))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(memStream);
    var message = from arrayOfStock in doc.Elements("Message")
                  select arrayOfStock;
}
```

And it seems to return the ArrayOfStock but also includes the message node itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
var arrayOfStockNodes = from arrayOfStock 
                        in doc.Root.Elements("ArrayOfStock") 
                        select arrayOfStock;
```

Because you want to have the `ArrayOfStock` tag, you should specify it...

Comment: That query expression is actually a no-op.

Comment: `doc.Root.Elements("ArrayOfStock")` by itself already returns the sequence of XElements desired. The `from ... select ...` syntax does not do anything else.

Comment: I know. I just corrected the original code, so the OP directly sees the difference

Comment: @abatishchev: Your edit didn't add any value to my post, so I did a rollback. Please refrain from such edits in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664244/using-linq-to-xml-to-match-deeper-descendant-elements/5664360#5664360) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be more than one:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> arraysOfStock = doc.Root.Elements("ArrayOfStock");
```

If there can be only one:

```
XElement arrayOfStock = doc.Root.Element("ArrayOfStock");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var result = from c in XDocument.Load("PATH_OF_XML_FILE").Descendants("ArrayOfStock")
                          select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.Descendants("ArrayOfStock").Concat(new[] { doc.Root });
```